# Html.BeginForm in MVC3 is rendering too much

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code. Note that I am not using a using as I want to begin and end the form in two different areas of my code. Has anyone seen this action where the helper adds "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm". I cannot see why this is added.

```
Code:
 @Html.BeginForm(new { action = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue })

@{ Html.EndForm() }

Result:
<form action="/adminTests/Edit" method="post">System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm
```

When I use the following I don't get the "System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm"

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { action = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue }))
    {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BeginForm/EndForm` helpers don't return a `IHtmlResult` so you should use them like this:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm(new { action = ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue }); }

    ...

@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

Comment: a technically correct answer but with an incomplete explanation of why.  You also display a fundamental lack of understanding of how the helper actually works in your comments on my answer.  I suggest you dig into the source code to understand your tools better.  In this case it's a small thing, but knowing how your tools work is a critical component to improvement as a programmer.

Comment: @tvanfosson, you are correct. Sorry for my misunderstanding. The BeginForm method does indeed write to the response stream. I will definitely dig into the source code to fill the gaps in my knowledge about how this helper is implemented internally.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap that in a using statement.  BeginForm writes directly to the response stream, it isn't intended to return a string like the other helpers.  The way you are using it, it is writing it's output, then returning the MvcForm object which, when disposed, will write the closing form tag.  Instead, your syntax forces it to call ToString on the returned object resulting in the output you see.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm(...
{
   ...
}
```

**Edit**: Since you can't wrap it in a using statement, you need to either explicitly close the form with HTML or call EndForm later.  In either case you have to use the BeginForm (and EndForm) in a code block instead of using it with the string output syntax.  Both of these methods write directly to the response stream.

```
@{ Html.BeginForm() ..  }

</form>  or   @{ Html.EndForm() }
```

Here's the relevant bits of the code for those who think I'm wrong (without permission):

```
public static void EndForm(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
    HttpResponseBase httpResponse = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response;
    httpResponse.Write("</form>");  // <-- look ma, Response.Write()
}

private static MvcForm FormHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string formAction, FormMethod method, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) {
    TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    // action is implicitly generated, so htmlAttributes take precedence.
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("action", formAction);
    // method is an explicit parameter, so it takes precedence over the htmlAttributes.
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("method", HtmlHelper.GetFormMethodString(method), true);

    HttpResponseBase httpResponse = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response;
    httpResponse.Write(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag)); <-- and here
    return new MvcForm(htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Response);
}
```

Comment: BeginForm doesn't write directly to the response stream. It returns an MvcForm instance.

Comment: @Darin, you're wrong.  It both writes the start tag and returns an MvcForm instance.  Disposing of the MvcForm instance writes the closing tag.  I've implemented a couple of similar containers using the same pattern.  Take a look at the source at http://aspnet.codeplex.com.  The relevant method is FormHelper located in FormExtensions.cs (System.Web.Mvc.Html).

Comment: tvanfosson - based on what u said is it okay for me to use the method suggested by Darin? I don't want to leave any "hanging" objects

Comment: @TonyG I would use the using if possible. If the closing tag goes in a different file, then you won't be able to. Generally, though, I would think that's probably a code smell - the form would typically be wholly contained a view. If it is located elsewhere then you can't wrap it in a using (since the closing tag will be written immediately). I wouldn't worry about it too much as by the time the dispose method is called on the MvcForm object is called the response will be in the users browser. AFAIK there are no unmanaged resources, the Disposable pattern is only used to allow the closing tag.

Comment: +1 to take you back to zero for this answer (WTF?!). I have had to write my own BeginUploadForm for use by other devs where I'm working and had to dig into this myself. Cheers!

Comment: +1 to take this back into the positive. Great use of decompilation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username) <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </p>

        <p>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password) <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password) @Html.RouteLink("Forgot Password", "password") <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </p>

        <p class="mtop10">              
            <div class="float-left small blue super-button">
                <a class="auto-submit" href="#">Login</a>
            </div>
            <div class="alt-action">
                or @Html.RouteLink("Register", "register")
            </div>
        </p>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Didn't you read the question? The OP explicitly said he cannot use `using` statement because he has this in two different areas of code.

Comment: @Darin - that must have been added via a later edit as I certainly didn't see it.

Comment: Sorry I maybe was not very clear where I mentioned about the "using". Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also saw `System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm` when using:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)
```

The following change fixed it:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", "POST");
```

Seems like `FormMethod.Post` forces the unwanted output but I can't explain it better than that.  The change worked for me though.